# Codeigniter Controller Naming issue

Tags: codeigniter-3

In codeigniter I have using class name `Login` having controller file name `login.php`. It is working fine in localhost but when i am uploading it to the cpanel then it is showing 404 error. In that case we need to make the controller First letter Capital. Mean the controller name should be `Login.php`. Can you tell me the solution why it is working in localhost and not in cpanel. Because I have not seen this kind of rules in codeigniter user_documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming) and reason for that is you are possibly using Windows in local development which is case insensitive meaning OS interprets lower and capital case equaly.